# On text change of anchor tag show/hide a div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want div `lds-roller` to only show while the text an ID `searchFor` `anchor tag` is equal to `_`. The change in text should happen with an HTTP response.

```
<div class="lds-roller"><div></div><div></div><div>
</div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div></div>
                <p>
                      <span class="r"> 
                               <span class="andom">
                                  <a href="{% pageurl post %}#disqus_thread" id="searchFor"> _
                                            </a>
                                </span>
                      </span>
                  </p>
```

Css for `lds-roller` is as follows.

```
.lds-roller {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
```

I have tried numerous ways but they seem to always either keep showing the `div`, not displaying the `div` or making the `div` disappear before the text has even changed.

`JS` function has usually gone along the lines of this

```
$(function () {
   if ($("#searchFor").text() === "_")
   {
       $('.lds-roller').show();
   }
   else{
       $('.lds-roller').hide();
   }

})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to bind the function to an event. For example in jQuery you can use something like this:

```
    $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#searchFor", function() {
         if ($("#searchFor").text() === "_") {
           $('.lds-roller').show();
         }
         else {
          $('.lds-roller').hide();
         }

    });
```

At the moment, your code is running once on load time and that is why it only shows the div.

Comment: Incredible insight! Thank you! Never even thought load time being an issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in your js code. 
it should be like this :

```
$(function () {
   if ($("#searchFor").text() === "_")
   {
       $('.lds-roller').show();
   }
   else{
       $('.lds-roller').hide();
   }
});
```

and its works fine for me

Comment: Dan Iftinca has pointed out load time being the issue. Thank you for your contribution though